# Removing changes made to geany

Tags: uninstall, c++, ide, geany, compiler

Actually I am a newbie here and I installed geany IDE and made some changes to it like hiding the menu (using the full view ).
Now I want to undo those changes but don't know how to do it.
Can someone please tell me a way how I can do this . I have tried uninstalling it using  sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove geany and again installing it. But it didn't help.
Please help how to restore menu bar
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to start over is to remove or - less irrevocably - rename your personal geany configuration directory, either from the nautilus file manager (you will need to enable hidden files from the `View` menu, or by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), or from the command line using

```
mv ~/.config/geany{/,.old}
```

A new default version of the directory and its configuration files will be created next time you start geany.